# How to set a String as a key for an object?

Tags: javascript

Given

```
this.state = {email: "something", firstName: "something" }
const name = "email"
const value = this.state[name]
```

I want to make a new object like this

```
{email: "something"}
```

basically without the other stuff

I tried

```
const new = {name: value}
```

This makes it {name: "something"} I want {email: "something"}

but the key doesn't attach to a variable and I want email to not be known to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems with your code.  `new` is a reserved word, so you can't make a variable named `new`.  And second, what you're looking to do is something like this:

```js
const name = 'email';
const myObj = {
  [name]: 'something'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [] while providing key as a variable

```
var name = "email"
var value = "something"
{[name]: value}
=> {email: "something"}
```